# How to read data from a single RAID-1 Harddisk

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, nas, raid-1, acronis-diskdirector

I had a HP Gen8 Microserver with Windows 7 and two SATA harddisks in a RAID-1 combination.

Now this server is broken and I want to read data from one of the hard disks in a normal Windows 10 PC.

The disk connects, but Windows displays an "unused partition".
I tried Acronis Disk Director 11 to read the partition, but this did not work.

Does anyone know how to read data from this hard disk?

Comment: Have you tried `systemrescuecd` or something similar? These linux-based tools typically work quite problen-free, allowing you to copy your files to another medium.

Answer (score 1):

"RAID1 configuration" does not necessarily mean that your Microserver is just duplicating one existing drive that can be easily read on any windows machine. The microserver might write administrative information p.e. at the beginning of the drive to know that your two drives belong together followed by the disc content.
I would therefore examine the drive with a disc editor to see if it's setup follows partitioning rules with regards to the old MBR style or GPT.

If that is not the case the easiest way to read out would be to buy or rent another Microserver corresponding to your failed machine for readout purposes.

Otherwise you will have to reverse engineer the on-disc format which might be easy as described above.
You would then simply use ddrescue to duplicate one of your drives to a file or a disc but instead of starting at the beginning of the source drive you would start where the MBR (maybe followed by a GPT) beginns which might be located just one or a few sectors behind the first sector on the disc.